# how can i test a webpack bundle containing typescript using jest?

Tags: typescript, webpack, jestjs, puppeteer

I'm bundling a minimal typescript function into a bundle with webpack. I would like to test it using jest with puppeteer but get an error when the test tries to call into the bundle:

```
Evaluation failed: TypeError: foo is not a function
```

The code is a slight fork of a small working javascript project:

```
[https://github.com/batwicket/example-jest-puppeteer-express-webpack][1]
```

I've tried running webpack to look at the resulting bundle and setting the DEBUG environment variable to get verbose output but there doesn't appear to be an obvious issue. Puppeteer is running in server-side mode. Typescript defaults to commonjs, so perhaps there is a problem with the export. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is fairly simple. Instead of

```
return foo()
```

use

```
return foo.default()
```